# Better app architecture for using Backbone JS or Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

I am using the Parse Javascript SDK to build an app which is quite similar to using Backbone JS. As I am building up my App, I become more and more confused of the single-page application concept and have no idea about the best practice. I here seek for help evaluating my app architecture.

My app aims to provide the following functions:

- User registration, profile editing, log in.
- Search for users that meet a criteria

I built a router as follows:

```
var IndexRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "users/new": "signup",
        "sessions/new": "signin",
        "users/:id/edit": "edit",
        "users": "searchResults"
        "": "index",
    }
    ...
}
```

The index page contains three elements, a jumbotron, a search bar and a list of three recently registered users. I have created views using Parse.View for them separately.

After the user click the search button, I would like the page only showing a list of search results, no jumbotron, no list of three recently registered users. What I am doing is just manually set those views' content to empty, like:

```
searchResults: function(){
    $('#jumbotron').html('');
    $('#recentlyCreatedUsers').html('');
    //create and then render the search results' view
    ...
}
```

In a nut shell, my strategy is to create a view for each section that is NOT static. In the future, I would need to add a navbar whose content changes according to routes, then I need to create a view for it as well.

Am I on the right track? I actually find my index page has been split into multiple views.

Comment: seems fine to me. Although empty the content using `this.$el.find("#jumbotron").empty();` to ensure you're not moving out of the view's el.

Comment: @coding_idiot  Thanks. Now I can move on with confidence.